# ASP.NET MVC 4 DropDownList selectedindexchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm paging using webgrid in ASP .NET MVC 4.0 but i have some trouble . RowsPerPage property webgrid i want to choose in DropDownList . Everything is OK but when i go to page 2 or page 3 ... default RowsPerPage = 5 . I know why but i can't fix it . Please help my trouble . Here my code

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.rowsPerPage = 5;
        return View(new StudentModel().ListStudent());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string model)
    {
        ViewBag.rowsPerPage = int.Parse(Request.Form["paging"].ToString());
        return View(new StudentModel().ListStudent());
    }

}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  <link href="~/Assets/Styles/Admin/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="~/Assets/Styles/Admin/HomeIndexStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Assets/Js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Assets/Js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
}

@model List<Model.ADO.M_STUDENT>

@using(@Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.DropDownList("paging", new List<SelectListItem> {
    new SelectListItem{Text="1",Value="1"},
    new SelectListItem{Text="5",Value="5",Selected=true},
    new SelectListItem{Text="10",Value="10"}
  }, new { onchange = @"form.submit();"})
}

@{
  var webGird = new WebGrid(
    Model, rowsPerPage: ViewBag.rowsPerPage,
    defaultSort: "Update_At",
    columnNames: new[] { "ID", "Name", "Address", "Email", "Phone", "Status", "Update_By", "Update_At" }
  );
  webGird.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
  @webGird.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover table-striped")
}
```

Comment: Because you have `new SelectListItem{Text="5", Value="5", Selected=true},

Comment: Thanks . I know it but i dont have ideal to fix it :(

Comment: Then create a view model containing a property for `int Paging` (and the `SelectList` while you at it) so you can strongly bind to your model and stop that awful use of `Request.Form["paging"]`

Comment: If create model or view paging but when debug model paging is reset and = null . That not create idea

Comment: What are you talking about? My comment was to use a view model to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what happens when you go to page 2 or 3 is the WebGrid sends GET request to the server. And on GET action handler you have this:

```
ViewBag.rowsPerPage = 5;
```

So you are resetting `rowsPerPage` all the time.

Actually the proper way to handle these changes in `rowsPerPage` should not be form submit. POST requests are used when data is supposed to be changed on server (like written to DB). Nothing like that happens here, so proper way to go is to:

1. Make form do GET requests instead of POST

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get){
   ...
   ```
2. Make WebGrid the part of the same form.
3. Get rid of POST action handler, as we are not doing POST anymore, and in GET handler have something like (not tested code here):

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Index(string paging)
   {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(paging))
       {
           // alternatively use TryParse
           ViewBag.rowsPerPage = int.Parse(paging);
       }
       else
       {
           // default value
           ViewBag.rowsPerPage = 5;
       }
   ```
4. Change your DropDwonList markup to decide on selected item based on ViewBag value:

   ```
   @Html.DropDownList(
       "paging", 
       new SelectList(
           new List<SelectListItem>{
               new SelectListItem{Text="1",Value="1"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="5",Value="5"},
               new SelectListItem{Text="10",Value="10"}
           }, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.rowsPerPage),
       new { onchange = @"form.submit();"})
   ```

   or even simpler

   ```
   @Html.DropDownList(
       "paging", 
       new SelectList(
           new List<int>{1, 5, 10}, ViewBag.rowsPerPage),
       new { onchange = @"form.submit();"})
   ```

Also, as a side note, you should really consider widening your model to carry all the data in it, like choices for page size, user selection, page number perhaps - otherwise your code will grow harder and harder to maintain.

Comment: I have just do it but you can see deafault new SelectListItem{Text="5",Value="5",Selected=true}, and always ViewBag.rowsPerPage = 5;

Comment: @user3883921, add another point to change the way selected item is chosen

Comment: Thanks . But in selectlist have 1 values is : System.web.mvc.selectitem :( . Can't show value 1 5 10

Comment: @Andrei, That should be `... new SelectList( new SelectListItem{..}, ...), "Value", "Text", ViewBag.rowsPerPage))`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke You can write all . Thank you very much :D

Comment: @StephenMuecke, there is an [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that accepts an IEnumerable and an object for selected value. And yeah, I agree that all this should be in viewmodel

Comment: @Andrei, That only works when `T` in `IEnumerable<T>` is a value type. In this case without specifying the `Value` and `Text` properties, it will render all options as "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem" (i.e. the `.ToString()` value of the object)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, should have thought of that myself. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you . But this code cant catch event onchange in dropdownlist :(

Comment: @user3883921, yes, you should keep that part from your original code. Don't just copy-paste answers, sometimes they are not complete solutions, but rather a guidance of how to solve a problem

Comment: @Andrei yes but in my code have onchange event . But your code dont have , so when i run your code and select dropdownlist no matter what happens . You can fix code have event onchange for me . Thanks

Comment: @Andrei no change anything because , when submit form reload page and default Request.Form["paging"] = null

Comment: @user3883921, oh, just realized that there is no form with get, so you need to declare paging as param in the action. Amended

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model to represent what you want to display and edit so that you can strongly bind to your properties

```
public class StudentVM
{
  [Display(Name = "Items per page")]
  public int Paging { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PageList { get; set; }
  public List<M_STUDENT> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller (your not changing data so the post method should be deleted)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int? paging)
{
  var pageList = new int[]{ 1, 5, 10 };
  StudentVM model = new StudentVM()
  {
    Paging = paging ?? 5,
    PageList = new SelectList(pageList),
    Students = // your query to return the students
  };
  return View(model );
}
```

And change your view to

```
@model yourAssembly.StudentVM
@using(@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Paging)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Paging, Model.PageList)
}
@{
  var webGird = new WebGrid(
    Model.Students, rowsPerPage: Model.Paging, // modify this
    ....
```

And the script to submit the form

```
<script>
  $('#Paging').change(function() {
    $('form').submit();
  });
</script>
```